# What's the difference between `-Contains` and `-In` in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

Other than the obvious reversal of the parameter order, what is the difference between the `-Contains` operator and PowerShell 3.0's new `-In` operator?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In short, there is no difference that you haven't already described.

The difference is which value is on the left vs. the right side:

```psh
$arr = @(4,5,6)

$arr -contains 5
5 -in $arr
```

The other difference is that `-in` was introduced in PowerShell 3.0, so it won't work on earlier versions.

It's mostly a style thing; use the one that feels more natural for a specific situation.

Comment: PowerShell adopts Perl's "TMTOWTDI" wholeheartedly, I guess.

Comment: @briantist I know that `-contains` does not work with wildcard notation. Based off your post `-in` does not either?

Comment: @Speerian if you mean using `-like` syntax in a string such as `'apple','grapple','bot' -contains '*pple'`, then that is correct; it doesn't work with `-in` either.

Answer (score 6):

same same but different...

`-contains` check if array contains value:

```
$Array -contains $value
```

`-in` check if value in array:

```
$value -in $Array
```

**Example:**

```
$Array = 1..5

$Array -Contains 4
True

4 -in $Array
True
```